# How can I add event listener in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, calculator, event-listener

I'm trying to build a simple calculator where the operations will be done in a `Node.js` server. How can I add an event listener in the `HTML` page buttons so that when a button is clicked it does the calculation in the `Node.js` server?

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't write your code for you. Try asking a more specific question. What did you come up with, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The title says "add event listener in nodejs" and you've tagged it as "nodejs", but nodejs does not have buttons.  Those would be in a web page where your listeners would be done in browser-based Javascript, not nodejs Javascript.  Please clarify EXACTLY what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title is incorrect, as some users pointed out and you should throw some code snippets to showcase what you've been doing and where exactly your problem is.
From the form of the question and details, I would suggest you do some research into the differences between frontend and backend and the solution will be clearer. But regarding your specific issue, assuming you're using Node, probably with Express and some templating engine;

- You'll want to attach a `onClick` listener to your button in your `ejs`/`pug`/`haml` file
- Get the data from your `form` in some way, either by `getElementById` or `FormData`
- Do a `fetch` with `POST` on the endpoint hitting your route -> controller with the data from your form or buttons
- `res.json(...)` or, more likely `res.render(...)` your page with the related data result

Answer (score -2):

Check out Node's [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter). With this class, you can emit events and listen for them. You can also create your own classes which extend `EventEmitter` and make use of its functionality like so:

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.emit('someEvent');
    }
}

const test = new MyClass();

test.on('someEvent', () => console.log('event was fired'));

test.doSomething();
```

Comment: It appears the OP wants to attach a listener to a button in a web page.  This code does not do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Then why is the post titled "How to add an event listener in Node.js"?

Comment: Yeah, that is confusing.  Maybe they have an assignment to have a calculator in a web page and have a nodejs server that does the calculations?  Who knows?  I think I'll comment asking for clarification and vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: Yes @mstephen actually the buttons are in a web page and the nodejs server does the calculation